# Scrapy Save Downloadable Files

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a scrapy web crawler that saves the html from the pages that I visit. I also want to save the files that I crawl with their file extension.

This is what I have so far
**Spider class**

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my name'  
    start_urls = ['my url']
    allowed_domains = ['my domain']
    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_item", follow= True),
  )

    def parse_item(self,response): 
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['html'] = response.body
        return item
```

**pipelines.py**

```
save_path = 'My path'

if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.makedirs(save_path)

class HtmlFilePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        page = item['url'].split('/')[-1]
        filename = '%s.html' % page
        with open(os.path.join(save_path, filename), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(item['html'])
        self.UploadtoS3(filename)

    def UploadtoS3(self, filename):
    ...
```

Is there an easy way to detect if the link ends in a file extension and save to that file extension? What I currently have will save to .html regardless of the extension.

I think that I could remove

```
filename = '%s.html' % page
```

and it would save as it's own extension, but there are cases where I want to save as html instead, such as if it ends in aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
   if not '.' in page:
        fileName = '%s.html' % page        
    else:
        fileName = page
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
import os

extension = os.path.splitext(url)[-1].lower()
#check if URL has GET request parameters and remove them (page.html?render=true)
if '?' in extension:
    extension = extension.split('?')[0]
```

Might want to check if that returns empty - for cases such as 'http://google.com' where there isn't a `.format` at the end.

Comment: What exactly does if '?' look for?

Comment: It checks if URL has GET request parameters and removes them. Example: `http://google.com/page.html?render=true`